# Walking through directory path and opening them with trimesh

Tags: python, subdirectory, trimesh

I have the following code:

```
import os
import trimesh

# Core settings
rootdir = 'path'
extension = ".zip"


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if not root.endswith(".zip"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".stl"):
                mesh = trimesh.load(file)
```

And I get the following error:

```
ValueError: File object passed as string that is not a file!
```

When I open the files one by one however, it works. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because `file` is the *filename*, not the full filepath

Fix that by using `os.path.join` with the containing directory:

```
mesh = trimesh.load(os.path.join(root,file))
```

Comment: oh I wanted to say skip if folder ends with ".zip", how I could do that? Thank you very much for the answer

Comment: Specifying the whole path and including `file_type='stl'` inside load command also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question. However, you might be interested in noting that there is now a less complicated paradigm for this situation. It involves using the `pathlib` module.

I don't use `trimesh`. I will process `pdf` documents instead.

First, you can identify all of the `pdf` files in a directory and its subdirectories recursively with just a single line.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> for item in path.glob('**/*.pdf'):
...     item
... 
WindowsPath('C:/Quantarctica2/Quantarctica-Get_Started.pdf')
WindowsPath('C:/Quantarctica2/Quantarctica2_GetStarted.pdf')
WindowsPath('C:/Quantarctica2/Basemap/Terrain/BEDMAP2/tc-7-375-2013.pdf')    WindowsPath('C:/Quantarctica2/Scientific/Glaciology/ALBMAP/1st_ReadMe_ALBMAP_LeBrocq_2010_EarthSystSciData.pdf')
WindowsPath('C:/Quantarctica2/Scientific/Glaciology/ASAID/Bindschadler2011TC_GroundingLines.pdf')

WindowsPath('C:/Quantarctica2/Software/CIA_WorldFactbook_Antarctica.pdf')
WindowsPath('C:/Quantarctica2/Software/CIA_WorldFactbook_SouthernOcean.pdf')
WindowsPath('C:/Quantarctica2/Software/QGIS-2.2-UserGuide-en.pdf')
```

You will have noticed that (a) the complete paths are made available, and (b) the paths are available within object instances. Fortunately, it's easy to recover the full paths using `str`.

```
>>> import fitz
>>> for item in path.glob('**/*.pdf'):
...     doc = fitz.Document(str(item))
...
```

This line shows that the final `pdf` document has been loaded as a `fitz` document, ready for subsequent processing.

```
>>> doc
fitz.Document('C:\Quantarctica2\Software\QGIS-2.2-UserGuide-en.pdf')
```